# Code won't read special characters from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Does anyone know why am I having this issue. I am suspecting it has something to do with UTF8 and PHP.
I have this code here:

```
echo '<div id="container"><iframe src="http://statsheet.com/mcb/players/player/'.$this->view->string()->chunk($value->value).'" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -30px; height: 859px; margin-top: -333px; width: 1000px;"></iframe></div>';
```

> > .$this->view->string()->chunk($value->value).

This grabs value from the database that is associated to the userid and profile page

Now, problem is with the value that is stored in the database. Currently, the value is north-carolina/charls-matich.

The output says it's broken link. however, if I change the link to `http://statsheet.com/mcb/players/player/north-carolina/charls-/` and in the database I change `north-carolina/charls-matich` to simply matich than I get correct output.

What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get your problem. What's the value in the database, and what's the value you retrieve in php? Try using `var_dump` on the value retrieved from db.

Comment: Hey BigWolf, I am trying to store portion of the link in the database so that it matches the user profile page when called. This is constant :http://statsheet.com/mcb/players/player/ and this is addition to that: north-carolina/charls-matich. For some reason the rendering fails because of  - and /

Comment: What exactly is the value of the iframe's src attribute (in html)?

Comment: It is: iframe src="http://statsheet.com/mcb/players/player/north-carolina/charles-matich

Comment: So my issues are dash and slash within the link. How to solve that problem

Comment: If the value in the database is "north-carolina/charls-matich" and the src ends in "/north-carolina/charles-matich", what's the problem?

Comment: well, php won't render forward slash and hyphen for some reason. The value that comes from the database is the following: north-carolina/charles-matich

Comment: Two possibilities: the field is not large enough and is truncating the data or the dash is not actually a dash but another html entity. This can happen with copy/paste. Go into the database and manually replace the visible dash with the correct dash character.